# Force RDP connections to ask for username and password

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I connect to client systems every day. They all have different server policies. Some allow saving passwords, some don't. Either way, everything is in keepass.

The problem comes, when something is trying to use previous credentials, but then takes its sweet time to negotiate with the server only to find out that it in fact doesn't allow them and I have to re-enter the password.

I would prefer to reenter both the username and the password.

Is there any way to force this? I tried /prompt, but that didn't alter the behaviour at all.

Comment: Passwords are saved in your OS for each host you connect to if you chose to “remember my credentials.” The host doesn’t get to decide if you can save the password or not. Being you can simply not check “remember my credentials” when connecting or you can turn off “allow me to save my credentials” in the RDP file. And, You can also delete saved credentials in the Windows credential manager. So, I’m not particularly sure what the problem is or what your question is?

Comment: Check Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials and see if the saved credentials are in there. If they are, remove them.

Comment: @Appleoddity : With Windows server, you can disable the saving of passwords using group policies.

Comment: @Worthwelle : While this works, it isn't permanent, as it will still remember the user name - something I want to avoid.

Comment: I’m not sure we are on the same page. The passwords are saved on YOUR computer. The server you are connecting to has NO control over your computer. It cannot decide if you save passwords or not. The functionality of saving passwords is 100% on your computer - unless you are suggesting your computer is under the control of group policy on a domain. This is a non-issue. I think you are misunderstanding how this works. If you don’t want to save the passwords or to not remember your username then do not select those  options when you are connecting to the server. It’s your choice.

Comment: @Appleoddity : No, I am not misunderstanding. The [RDP host can disable password saving](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/92824-enable-always-prompt-password-upon-remote-desktop-connection.html). This overrides user control. However, that isn't even the point here, you are _completely_ missing what I am asking. I am looking for a way that will prevent the RDP client from remembering ANY part of the credentials, including the username. I can tell it not to remember the password, but I want it to prompt for both.

Comment: There is an [option to save credentials or not, plus group policy to force it to be disabled.](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/prevent-saving-of-remote-desktop-credentials-in-windows/) my point is, if you don’t want to save it, don’t use the option to save it.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://woshub.com/how-to-clear-rdp-connections-history/ It provides a batch file you can run after logging in to clear the connection history. If you need, you can probably alter it to look for specific user names and just remove those.

Comment: @Appleoddity thank you for continuing not to understand. This is appreciated.

Comment: @Worthwelle: Thank you. This is likely the most correct answer I can get, as it does not seem that windows has a way to prevent the username history. I'll play around with this, leaving the few entries that I actually want in the list, alive.